# Copy paste Excel data between two sheets using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, sheet1 and sheet2. From sheet1 data, I have to copy data and paste it into sheet2, then again from sheet1 I have to copy another different set of data and paste it into sheet2 last line, where I pasted data 1st time.

```
Sub Copy_chains_to_other_sheet()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>1", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$681").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*antaris*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

This is the macro I wrote, but I don't know how to proceed. Because one time I have 5 rows of data that time I need to copy data from sheet1 and paste in sheet2 and with next set of data I need to paste it in 6th row, but another time I have 8 row of data that time I need to paste the next set of data from 9the row onwards, so how to deal with this.

Comment: What determines the Range that needs copied?

Comment: Looping through a given range to look for cells that meet your criteria, then setting the boundaries of the range, you can loop through that range using variables for the row number and column numbers instead of letters.  I can show you once I understand what determines your logic for selecting your ranges.

Comment: The range copied is not fixed. according to the filtering condition it will differ. The above code which i gave is recorded.Now the problem is, i am pasting data in another sheet, in that sheet i already pasted data from A1 to C3 for example now i need to paste next set of data in A4 column.

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking, sorry.What determines the range, i am not getting it. I cant able to add image also, i don't know how to explain my situation.

Comment: I apologize.  You are saying that the range changes.  How do you decide what it is in the first place?  I understand that you pick up where you left off from the previous range on all subsequent copies.  But when you decide in the first use, how do you come up with the range?  One time is 5, another time 8.  What makes that decision for you?  Why 5 or 8?

Comment: it depends on previous data which i placed in the sheet. 1st i filter a in sheet1 contains jack, so i am getting a set of data it may be 5 row or 8 row, it depends on data which i receive. Then next i will go to same data and filter contains peter and copy those data and paste where the previous data ends. i use criteria in column A to filter, but i copy from A to I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to copy the results of successive autofiltered data from Sheet1 to a continuous "list" in Sheet2.  If this is so then perhaps try the following to get you going.  You will need to alter the variables/names to suit your requirement, I have made some assumptions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyAFs()
Dim wsONE As Worksheet, wsTWO As Worksheet
Dim ONEstrow As Long, ONEendrow As Long, ONEstcol As Long, ONEendcol As Long
Dim TWOstrow As Long, TWOnextrow As Long, TWOstcol As Long
Dim crit1col As Long, crit2col As Long
Dim crit1 As String, crit2 As String

Set wsONE = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTWO = Sheets("Sheet2")
ONEstrow = 1
ONEstcol = 1
ONEendcol = 10
TWOstrow = 1
TWOstcol = 1
crit1 = "antaris"
crit2 = "1"
crit1col = 1
crit2col = 8

    With wsTWO
        TWOnextrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TWOstcol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

'clear autofilter
wsONE.AutoFilterMode = False

    'apply autofilter
    With wsONE
        ONEendrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ONEstcol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            With .Range(.Cells(ONEstrow, ONEstcol), .Cells(ONEendrow, ONEendcol))
                'set autofilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=crit1col, Criteria1:=crit1
                .AutoFilter Field:=crit2col, Criteria1:=crit2
            End With
    End With

    'copy filtered range without header
    With wsTWO
        wsONE.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=.Range(.Cells(TWOnextrow, TWOstcol), .Cells(TWOnextrow, TWOstcol))
    End With

    'clear autofilter
    wsONE.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Barryleajo the code works fine. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Barryleajo, In the above code you wrote any copying the data to another sheet, but in the same scenario i need to delete the row instead of copying to another sheet. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: @Vigneshwaran Kandaswamy to respect the 'rules' and 'spirit' of this site please post another question.  Also make it clear whether the row you want to delete is within the autofiltered range;  whether it may be one or more rows and what criteria for deletion apply.  Of course I (for one) will help if I can.